# Angular11 test: ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-test, testbed, angular11

I used `ResizeObserver` in my component and its works fine.
But get such error when running ut:

```
    ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined

      133 |             });
      134 |         
    > 135 |         this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
          |                                   ^
      136 |             const entry = entries.find((e) => e.target === this.wrapper._elementRef.nativeElement);
      137 |             if (entry && entry.contentRect) {
      138 |                 if (this.select && this.select.isOpen) {
```

I use TestBed to create component:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
```

I can't understand why has this error, I just new an object.

ts version

```
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer might be helpful https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/issues/50#issuecomment-488064120

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Resolved it by:

```
// import section ...

window.ResizeObserver =
    window.ResizeObserver ||
    jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        disconnect: jest.fn(),
        observe: jest.fn(),
        unobserve: jest.fn(),
    }));

describe('', () => {
  // test ...
});
```

Comment: This also works for testing Vue components using Vuetify 3 and Jest

Comment: This should be the selected answer, since it demonstrates clearly "where to put the code" - thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **ResizeObserver** **polyfill**
is not imported in your testing module.

A proper solution would be to stub the global implementation.

Example Implementation:

```
global.ResizeObserver = jest.fn(() => ({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
}))
```