# ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am writing tests using Jest for component which used chart.js to create a line chart. I am getting below error when I am running the tests.

> ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined
>
> ```
>   290 |   }
>   291 |   ngAfterViewInit() {
> > 292 |     this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, this.chartConfig);
>       |                  ^
>   293 |   }
>   294 |
>   295 |   ngOnInit() {
>
>   at createResizeObserver (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:2428:20)
>   at DomPlatform.addEventListener (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:2502:21)
>   at _add (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:7051:16)
>   at attached (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:7070:7)
>   at Chart.bindResponsiveEvents (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:7079:7)
>   at Chart.bindEvents (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:7023:12)
>   at Chart._initialize (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:6547:8)
>   at new Chart (../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js:6512:8)
> ```

ResizeObserver is being used internally by the chart.js and i am not using explicitly anywhere. Does any one have a solution for this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you using the `use-resize-observer` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-resize-observer) library or the `resize-observer` hook (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/resize-observer)?

If your test is failing on a component using `use-resize-observer` library, you need to mock the service in your test file (if you're using React):

```js
jest.mock('use-resize-observer', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

I see that you use Angular, so this post should be useful: [Angular11 test: ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591705/angular11-test-referenceerror-resizeobserver-is-not-defined)

```js
window.ResizeObserver =
    window.ResizeObserver ||
    jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        disconnect: jest.fn(),
        observe: jest.fn(),
        unobserve: jest.fn(),
    }));

describe('', () => {
  // test ...
});
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're encountering an error message like *"ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined"* while running tests using **vitest**, **react**, and **@headlessui/react**, it's likely because ResizeObserver is not available in your test environment.

This error can be fixed by stubbing or mocking the *ResizeObserver* using **vi.stubGlobal()**. Below is an example on how to do this:

```
// Mock the ResizeObserver
const ResizeObserverMock = vi.fn(() => ({
  observe: vi.fn(),
  unobserve: vi.fn(),
  disconnect: vi.fn(),
}));

// Stub the global ResizeObserver
vi.stubGlobal('ResizeObserver', ResizeObserverMock);
```

Here's what each line does:

1. `const ResizeObserverMock = vi.fn(() => ({ ... }));`: Creates a mock implementation of the ResizeObserver. The object returned by this function has observe, unobserve, and disconnect methods as empty functions. This is the minimum required for your tests to run without throwing a reference error.
2. `vi.stubGlobal('ResizeObserver', ResizeObserverMock);`: Stubs the global ResizeObserver object with the mock implementation. After this line, any code within your test that uses ResizeObserver will use this mocked version instead, thus resolving the "ResizeObserver is not defined" error.

You can place this code in your test setup file to make sure it's executed before your tests run.

Hope this helps! Happy testing!